# Obtain a window coordinates from processID or hWnd

Tags: window, coordinates

does anyone know if you can get the coordinates of a window using the .NET framework or via pinvoking?

I would have the processID or mainwindowhandle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI, you can use
System.Windows.Forms.Control cr= System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle); 
now u can get location of that control.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Forms API, form.Top and form.Left should do.

If all you have is the process Id, you can iterate through the process's widows using [EnumWindowsProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633498%28VS.85%29.aspx) windows API method. once you get the window's handle which you want, you can query for its size and position.

Comment: Which application? Please mention your specific scenario in the question.

Comment: Is your question this: how can I get the position of the main window of an application if I have its process ID?

Comment: I want to center a form over an application that i did not produce. so i need to somehow gets its coordinates to center it correctly.

Comment: looks like you can query for its size and position with GetWindowRect